# Getting the starting and ending date of a week when a date is provided in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need the starting date and the ending date of the week when I input a date .

NOTE: The week has to start from SUNDAY and end by SATURDAY

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,GETDATE()),0)-1 'Start date',
DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,GETDATE())+1,0)-2 'End Date'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic "week starts from Sunday and ends on Saturday"

```
select "start_of_week" = dateadd(week, datediff(week,0, GETDATE()),-1);
select "end_of_week" = dateadd(week, datediff(week,0, GETDATE()),5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT GETDATE()-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())+1 AS StartOfWeek, GETDATE()+(7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())) AS EndOfWeek
```

Here, `DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())` returns 4 (Week day number) - [Today **18-Jun-2014**]